# Webscraping - What would cause my requests.get() function to take much longer than the CPU time?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a webpage, but the time it takes 'requests.get()' is much longer than I am used to.

What would cause the large difference in the CPU time vs Wall time as shown below? I have quit all other applications, updated the requests package but have not received any luck here.

```
%%time 
import requests

# Initial Scrape
KMX_url = "https://www.carmax.com/cars?location=all"

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(KMX_url, headers = headers)

CPU times: user 180 ms, sys: 28.5 ms, total: 209 ms
Wall time: 2min 34s
```

Comment: CPU time should be a tiny fraction of wall time -- over the internet, your wall time will be dominated by network latency and the latency of the remote service. That said, if you're scraping a website and the administrator is competent you're probably being detected and tarpitted.

Comment: @DanielPryden is there a way to address that?

Comment: You're asking them for information. (That's why it's called a "request".) They can always just say no, or decide to ignore your request, or lots of other things. They aren't obligated to give you what you want, when you want, unless you have a contractual relationship with them, which I doubt. Could you do (increasingly unethical) things to make it harder for them to detect you? Probably. But it's an arms race, and they probably have more time, money, and resources to throw at it than you do.